# how to count how many times a user logs in?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to have a detail statistics about each of my site's user
How can I count how many times each user logs in?

Python.V=3.4
Django.V=1.7

## In my models.py

I just extended the users' model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(3), MaxValueValidator(99)])
    birth_day = models.DateField(default=date(2015, 1, 1))
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX, default='N')
    about_me = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    #other fields here

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s's profile" % self.user
```

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: I would suggest to start by https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/analytics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new field to `UserProfile` model to store the number of successful logins of the user and then, listen for [`user_logged_in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in) signals.

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

def login_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    user.userprofile.login_count = user.userprofile.login_count + 1
    user.userprofile.save()

user_logged_in.connect(login_user)
```

Note that, it only counts actual `login` actions, where the previous session of the user is expired at the time he visits your site. If session is valid, he will not have to log in again so `login_count` won't be incremented.

So if you want to log user in whenever he opens his browser, you can tell session framework to set a [`browser-length cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions) in your **settings.py** file:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

Comment: Note; this will only track when user actually has to login; depending on how your set sessions, if the user regularly visits your page, he/she won't have to login each time (maybe years before they have to again).

Comment: @warath-coder I is not relevant with the scope of the question but thanks I've added it as a note into my answer.

Comment: Thanks, In Django 1.7 the `get_profile()` method on the User model are removed. I should use `.userprofile`.

Comment: I have a basic question, how do you learn Django such this deeply?

Comment: @AlirezaGhaffari lots of practice... do projects with django; but first start by doing the entire tutorial and make sure you understand it.

Comment: @warath-coder - do you have a preferred solution to handle the instance when the user is on the site frequently enough that he/she does not have to login because cookies don't expire? I'd like to track, by date, when the user uses the site, or not.

Comment: @Vishal look at creating your own middleware to track this. I've also used that to track the number of devices they are logged in from, and if they want can log out of all devices.